# What is the effect of caliper size in case-control study

Tags: effect-size, case-control-study

I'm reading some literature on case-control studies, in which they discuss the use of "calipers" for matching on continuous variables.

However, I can't seem to find anything about the relationship between caliper size and the effect size.

My intuition is if large calipers are used, then the strata has higher variance and it may be more difficult to detect a difference. Can anyone speak to this?